# ListView on Nativescript+Angular is taking up only half of the vertical screen. Using Iphone simulator

Tags: ios, css, angular, ios-simulator, nativescript

I have a listview under actionBar, which seems to be taking only half of the screen vertical real estate. The list scrolls within half of the screen.

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical" height="100%">
    <ActionBar class="action-bar">
        <NavigationButton visibility="collapsed"></NavigationButton>
        <GridLayout columns="auto,*,auto" height="100%" width="100%">
            <Label col="0" text="&#xf0c9;" class="fa" (tap)="onDrawerButtonTap()"></Label>
            <Label col="1" text="Menu" class="action-bar-title"></Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </ActionBar>
    <!-- <ScrollView orientation="vertical"> -->
        <ListView [items]="restaurant_menu" class="list-group">
                <ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index">
                    <StackLayout orientation="vertical" class="list-group-item">
                        <Label [text]="item.name"></Label>
                        <GridLayout columns="*,auto,auto,auto" rows="auto" orientation="horizontal" class="list-group-item">
                            <Label [text]="'Rs. '+item.price" col="0" row="0" verticalAlignment="top"></Label>
                            <Label *ngIf="order && order[item.name]>0" text="-" col="1" row="0" verticalAlignment="top" horizontalAlignment="right"></Label>
                            <Label *ngIf="order && order[item.name]>0" [text]="order[item.name]" col="1" row="0" verticalAlignment="top" horizontalAlignment="right"></Label>
                            <Label (tap)="build_order(item.name, '+')" text="+" col="1" row="0" verticalAlignment="top" horizontalAlignment="right"></Label>
                        </GridLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ng-template>
            </ListView> 
    <!-- </ScrollView> -->
</StackLayout>
```

setting the height to 100% doesn't change the outcome. What am I missing? I'm using native-core-theme and no css changes that dictates the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the StackLayout above ActionBar. ActionBar should be part of Page instance or just at root level in case of {N} Angular. ListView can be placed just below it, you don't need a StackLayout to wrap them up.

Comment: Why does wrapping listView in StackLayout cause it to be limited to stay within half a screen though? I've done the same to stack 1. category-of-list (in horizontal scrollable stack) and 2. list-under-the-category (listView) ... under one stack. The list seemed to be limited a certain portion of the screen. Something similar happened even in a nested ListView

Comment: StackLayout simply stacks the child components, the height must be known. But ListView's height can't be determined as the items are loaded dynamically. I guess if you set height of ListView to 100% that might work but it's overhead when the right / easy option is to remove StackLayout. The less elements on screen / processing time, the better performance is.